# Using LIKE operator for multiple words in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, where-clause, sql-like

I have a DataFrame `df` in `PySpark`, like a one shown below -

```
+-----+--------------------+-------+
|   ID|           customers|country|
+-----+--------------------+-------+
|56   |xyz Limited         |U.K.   |
|66   |ABC  Limited        |U.K.   |
|16   |Sons & Sons         |U.K.   |
|51   |TÜV GmbH            |Germany|
|23   |Mueller GmbH        |Germany|
|97   |Schneider AG        |Germany|
|69   |Sahm UG             |Austria|
+-----+--------------------+-------+
```

I would like to keep only those rows where `ID` starts from either 5 or 6. So, I want my final dataframe to look like this -

```
+-----+--------------------+-------+
|   ID|           customers|country|
+-----+--------------------+-------+
|56   |xyz Limited         |U.K.   |
|66   |ABC  Limited        |U.K.   |
|51   |TÜV GmbH            |Germany|
|69   |Sahm UG             |Austria|
+-----+--------------------+-------+
```

This can be achieved in many ways and it's not a problem. But, I am interested in learning how this can be done using `LIKE` statement.

Had I only been interested in those rows where `ID` starts from 5, it could have been done easily like this -

```
df=df.where("ID like ('5%')")
```

**My Question:** How can I add the second statement like `"ID like ('6%')"` with `OR - |` boolean inside `where` clause? I want to do something like the one shown below, but this code gives an error. So, in nutshell, how can I use multiple boolean statement using `LIKE and .where` here  -

```
df=df.where("(ID like ('5%')) | (ID like ('6%'))")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

`df = df.where('ID like "5%" or ID like "6%"')`

Comment: THANK YOU so much Pintu. Can you tell me as to why swapping ' with " did the trick?

Comment: The trick was to use **or** in place of |. Swapping of ' does not have any impact.

Comment: oh, I thought that we have to use pipe | in PySpark and **or** is not allowed. Surprised.

Comment: pyspark where statement supports both - dataframe operations as well as sql query. The one you (and even I) used is sql within where. So, **or** statement is supported here. The one Mike has suggested uses the dataframe operations, where you cannot use **or**.

Comment: I thought the same as well that it might have to do with SQL type syntax as opposed to DataFrame one. Thanks a ton Pintu. Very helpful.

Comment: I have the same question. But in my case, the problem is I have lots of words in a list. what can I do in that case??

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.where(F.col("ID").like('5%') | F.col("ID").like('6%'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In pyspark, SparkSql syntax:

```
where column_n like 'xyz%' OR column_n like 'abc%'
```

might not work.

Use:

```
where column_n RLIKE '^xyz|abc'
```

Explanation: It will filter all words either starting with `abc` or `xyz`.

This works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, well ‘like’ has worked perfect for me as well and code hasn’t broken. So, I would continue with it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @cph_sto : yes it may work for few cases but cases where you use variable substitution , for example 
where column_m='%(some_variable)s'     .If you use like operator with % along with this variable substitution then it will break the code as python will get confuse with the %

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.filter((col("ID").like("5%")) | (col("ID").like("6%")))
```